# Typeerror:name.tolowercase is not function in javascript - unresolved

Tags: javascript, node.js

Am new to Javascript ,Please help me resolve the below issue . I have the below function in 'appCommon.js' file and I have declared a variable to store the return type of function written in appCommon.js. Am facing an issue while converting it to LowerCase. Error : title.toLowerCase() is not a function.

appCommon.js :

```js
let appcommon = function() {

  this.randomString = function(length, chars) {
    var today = new Date();
    var dd = String(today.getDate()).padStart(2, '0');
    var mm = String(today.getMonth() + 1).padStart(2, '0'); //January is 0!
    var yyyy = today.getFullYear();

    today = mm + dd + yyyy;
    var result = 'Test-Name-' + today + '-';
    for (var i = length; i > 0; --i) result += chars[Math.round(Math.random() * (chars.length - 1))];
    return result;
  }
}

module.exports = new appcommon();
```

Test.js :

```js
var common = require("../common/appcommon")
var title = common.randomString(4, '0123456789');

let Test = function() {
  this.verifyFolder = function() {
    var name = title.toLowerCase();
    console.log(name);
  }
}

module.exports = new Test();
```

I tried converting it `.toString()` and storing it as `String(title)`, but couldnt resolve it.It is working fine when I hard code the value in 'Test.js' i.e, ex: var title = "Test-Name-06012020-3498' , it is converting to lowercase -- 'test-name-06012020-3498'.

Comment: What exactly does `common.randomString(4, '0123456789')` return?

Comment: Did you debug at all? What value does `title` have?

Comment: Your code has syntax errors. Code in first snippet, for loop don't have `{` and `}` and after return it have two `}`

Comment: @Kenny, there are no syntax errors, just horrible indentation.

Comment: @Kenny `for` doesn't need `{}` if it has only one expression below it. The two `}` are for the `randomString` and `appcommon` function

Comment: It is working fine when I move the function to Test.js..failing only when i call it from another js file.

Comment: correct,it doesnt require {} after for loop @Kenny

Comment: @zerkms : It is returning 'Test-Name-06052020-8569'

Comment: @Rahul `'Test-Name-06052020-8569'.toLowerCase()` works just fine

Comment: Show `typeof name`

Comment: @Paul Zaslavskij